# Angular 5 approach for creating reusable templates, not components

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5

My team is migrating some AngularJS (v 1.6.6) applications we already have in production in my company to Angular 5, and we still couldn't find a way to do one very nice thing we were able to do in AngularJS.

We could use directives in elements to pass attributes, access it, modify it's properties, modify attributes, build html from strings, append it to the element and compile it back into the scope. By doing this, all created elements would share the same scope as my active controller, and be able to access all it's methods and variables.

The following code illustrates this kind of solution:

```
export default ngModule => {

  ngModule.directive('hasPushList', ($compile) => {

    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function (sc, el, at) {
        el.removeAttr('has-push-list')
        var cls = at.hasPushList == 2 ? 'specPushListBox ' : 'pushListBox '
        el.attr('class', cls + at.class)
        var rp = at.maRepeat || 'x',
        tp =
        '<div class="pushedElm bc1i" ng-if="' + at.maDestination + '.length == 0">'+
          '<i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i> Selecione...'+
        '</div>'+
        '<div ng-repeat="' + rp + ' in ' + at.maDestination + '" ng-click="removeFromPushList(' + rp + ')">'+
          '<div class="pushedElm bcp8">'+
            '{{' + at.maOrigin + '[' + at.maOrigin + 'I.indexOf(' + rp + ')].' + (at.maShowKey || 'DS') + '}}'+
          '</div>'+
        '</div>'
        el.attr('ng-mouseenter', 'setPushList({ev: $event, or: ' + at.maOrigin + ', ds: ' + at.maDestination + ', ktp: "' + (at.maPushKey || 'VL') + '", kts: "' + (at.maShowKey || 'DS') + '", md: "' + at.maModel + '", mi: "' + at.maModelId + '", vn: "' + at.maVar + '"})')
        el.attr('ng-mouseleave', 'hidePushList()')
        el.append(tp)
        $compile(el)(sc)
      }
    }

  })

}
```

By doing this we can use the `setPushList()` function from main controller, manipulating its scope directly, without having to create a single directive with its own scopes and `setPushList()` functions multiple times, which reduces drastically the ammount of memory and processing used.

It's simple like that: a html customizable templating engine used only for reducing bundle size.

We tried to do it in Angular 5 by creating components and directives, but we couldn't find an effective way, as directives won't let me create templates and components have its own scopes that we would require us to create multiple @Inputs, @Outputs, Services, Observables, etc. to share data between different parts of our view, and this wouldn't perform well also in cases that too many components are loaded.

Is there any way to achieve this in Angular 5? I found something related to ElementRef and Renderer/Renderer2 core components, but it seems that these modules aren't for exactly this kind of purpose.

Comment: How are you sure angular components would not perform well? Why do you try to apply some hacks that used to be good in angularjs to angular? Why do you think AOT is less performant than compiling at the runtime? You should try the standard solutions first. Don't try to optimize the things that are not a problem yet

Comment: Have you looked at `ngTemplate` or `ngTemplateOutlet`? They may help.

Comment: @smnbbrv Our team were able to recreate exactly the same functionality in our Angular 5 system using components, event emitters and parent components subscriptions, but sometimes there are so many child components (about 800) that our app gets additional event listeners and multiplies the same variables from a parent component list option array in each child component, making it use almost twice the memory compared to the situation were we just create a larger single component with all necessary content and without additional scopes for each child component.

Comment: @DeborahK I'm going to take a look at these modules, thank you for the tip!

Comment: So you say you tried something and failed and instead of trying to solve the problem you invent weird stuff. Please post what you tried. Create a plunkr with 800 components that reproduces the problem. And then we can have a look.